# How to let phantomjs show dynamically loaded webpage?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

When I access https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=cell, there is "Results by year", a histogram under it and "Download CSV".

But when I access the same URL with the following script, I don't see them. Does anybody know why?

Is there a way to get the histogram along with "Download CSV" using a command line **scraper** ? Thanks.

```
$ cat phjsget.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys    
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path='/dev/null')
browser.get(sys.argv[1])
print browser.page_source.encode('utf-8')
browser.close()

$ ./phjsget.py https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=cell
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Results by year" and "Download CSV" are loaded in after the page has loaded with Javascript. wget will not execute Javascript. You can use a tool like PhantomJS or Selenium to simulate real browser behavior that will execute Javascript.

Comment: Have you noticed OP uses PhantomJS webdriver in Selenium and not wget?

Comment: @Vaviloff they edited their question after my response, OP was initially asking about using wget to download the webpage

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. They should have opened a new question of course.